Align widget at the end of the CustomScrollView but make it scrollable when screen too small
How to build a layout using CustomScrollView such that the bottom block:

Is in-line with other Slivers when the screen is small and view is scrollable
Is aligned to the bottom edge when screen is sufficiently big, but view is not scrollable

Don't want to use LayoutBuilder as the content of the blocks may vary e.g. depending on the font size, content shown etc.
Additionally, the content may be shown in a modal bottom sheet, so in a scrollable environment wrapping entire CustomScrollView. We can access the modal bottom sheet's controller.

Sample DartPad
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
              'Keep me either aligned to the bottom or in-line with other slivers'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),


Not sure if you can acheive that in a CustomScrollView.
Here is a workaround that might help
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      SliverFillRemaining(
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
                'Keep me either aligned to the bottom or in-line with other slivers'),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )


I think I've found the solution, by using SliverFillRemaining's fillOverscroll: false, hasScrollBody: false, arguments and putting the child within Align:
Updated DartPad
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
  SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: Container(
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
  SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: Container(
      height: 300,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
  ),
  SliverFillRemaining(
    fillOverscroll: false,
    hasScrollBody: false,
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
              'Keep me either aligned to the bottom or in-line with other slivers'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )

